# I have a AutoCompleteTextView and want to set single value

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/step1_textview_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_round_corner_borders"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:ems="10" />
```

Using below code to set text

```
areaAutoCompleteTextView.setText(objPropertyObject.getArea());
```

but it's not wokring

Comment: what is type of **objPropertyObject**

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so post the log

Comment: when i use that time also not working...... areaAutoCompleteTextView.setText("area");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code in your activity?

```
step1_textview_area.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            step1_textview_area.showDropDown();
        }
    },500);
    step1_textview_area.setText(objPropertyObject.getArea());
    step1_textview_area.setSelection(autoText.getText().length());
```

Comment: in first time value is not set, but when i click AutoCompleteTextView then my  search list showing and then value is saving but after first time loading activity i want to save this value